# В уведомлении об упоминании в чате вместо имени пользователя отображается его id

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, чат, уведомления

При упоминании пользователя в чате, на сайте появляется уведомление.
В нем вместо имени пользователя (`@VenZell`) показывается его `id` в чате (`@@141865`).

Если упоминается несколько пользователей, подобное поведение распространяется на всех.

В моем случае, в чат меня призывал модератор, поскольку я на протяжении некоторого времени отсутствовал на сайте. Возможно, это играет роль.

[Вот пример такого уведомления](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29183633#29183633):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> в чат меня призывал модератор, поскольку я на протяжении некоторого времени отсутствовал на сайте

Именно в этом и причина. Ник использовал так называемый супер-пинг, который действительно имеет формат `@@123456`, и уведомляет участника даже при полном отсутствии из чата.

Эта функция доступна только модераторам.

Comment: так тут больше вопрос, почему в чате показывает правильные имена, а в уведомлении пользователя `id`

Comment: ...в смысле, это не столько вопрос, сколько потенциальный багрепорт.

Comment: @Grundy вероятно, потому, что для суперпинга используется именно Id. В имя он превращается уже после отправки сообщения чата. Соответственно, в момент отправки имя неизвестно.